# How to fix run custom shell script 'Run Script' Failed in flutter iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, archive

I have a flutter IOS project and try to run it on a physicals device and it works,
now I need to archive it to get `Ipa` file to upload it to the app store.

I faced this problem in the image:
[image]

I have the latest version of flutter, and XCode 13.3, and I am using firebase in my project

so how can I fix this problem I am stacking in for two days and don't find the solution yet

Comment: which ios version are you using? How about you try to set it for ios 12 then do a clean and build again. And dont forget to delete the podfile.lock on your ios folder cause it is possible that this problem is related to dependencies..

Comment: hi did you solve the problem?

Comment: @YunusDikenlitarla hi, in my case the problem was there was no space on disk so I delete many item to fix this issue.